# data.table syntax equivalent to sapply?

Tags: r, data.table, n-gram

I am trying to analyses ngram of a corpus stored in a data.table. I want to calculate all the 1-gram (or 2,3,4-gram), store them, their count and in which row they appear in a data.table. I have managed using sapply:

```
smallCorpus<-data.table(id = 1:3,
                        corpus = c("<s> exactly how long do you want a you tube videos to be anyway </s>","<s> google scrapped the early version of its smart glasses in january </s>","<s> exactly how long do you want a you tube videos to be anyway </s> <s> today we are announcing the success of our integration test </s>"),
                        key="id")

library(stringi,tau)
genNgramTable<-function(cC,n){
    Count<- textcnt(cC[,corpus],n=n,split=" ",method="string",decreasing=TRUE)
    Ngram<-data.table(gram=names(Count),count=Count,key="gram")
    listOfOcc<-sapply(Ngram[,gram],
                      function(gram,corpus){which(stri_detect_fixed(corpus," "%s+%gram%s+%" "))},
                      cC[,corpus])
    Ngram<-Ngram[,Fkey:=listOfOcc]
}

gram1<-genNgramTable(smallCorpus,1L)
```

My question is: Is it possible to use a data.table call to do this (my hope is that it will be faster). I have tried:

```
genNgramTable<-function(cC,n){
    Count<- textcnt(cC[,corpus],n=n,split=" ",method="string",decreasing=TRUE)
    Ngram<-data.table(gram=names(Count),count=Count,key="gram")
    Ngram<-Ngram[,Fkey:=which(stri_detect_fixed(cC[,corpus]," "%s+%gram%s+%" "))]
}
```

it give the warning

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(Ngram, , `:=`(Fkey, which(stri_detect_fixed(cC[,  :
  Supplied 17 items to be assigned to 33 items of column 'Fkey' (recycled leaving remainder of 16 items).
```

and does only give me one number in the Fkey column. Moreover this number is outside the scope of my row numbers (1:3).

I will be grateful if someone can explain me why.

Comment: Fyi, it's polite to cut your problem down to a minimal example. Recommendations for doing that are over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481250/1191259 In this case, I'm guessing you don't need stringi and several functions to illustrate the question.